# PhantomJS connects to URL but CasperJS times out

Tags: javascript, testing, https, phantomjs, casperjs

Trying to write some tests with casperjs but the server I'm trying to connect connects fine using phantomjs, but gets hung up using casperjs any time it tries to make a connection to this app:
casper.start(MYURL) or casper.open(MYURL)

Casper works with other URLs, I'm just wondering is there anything that could be preventing casper from connecting to an app? (Note: when the app is not running on the server, casper could get to it and get the 502 Bad Gateway error at least. When the app's running, the script just seems to get stuck on the above code)

Also the app is running https so I'm using the flag --ignore-ssl-errors=true when running both scripts.

Just really confused since PhantomJS works perfectly fine.

Comment: Have installed CasperJS through npm? If yes, then it's possible that it's using another PhantomJS version. Is it an HTTPS URL? If yes, have you tried `--ssl-protocol=any`?

Comment: I've tried --ssl-protocol=any but it still gets hung up. I had an issue with ssl on both phantom & casper but the --ignore-ssl-errors fixed that. Both phantomjs and casperjs were installed using npm install -g.

Comment: Have you tried with both `--ignore-ssl-errors=true --ssl-protocol=any`?

Comment: Just found out they were both using phantomjs version 1.9.8 and yes I've tried with both

Comment: Well, that's really strange. Please add a **complete** (including the URL in question) and minimal script for PhantomJS and CasperJS that reproduces this error to your question.

Comment: Could it have something to do with ports? The server is running locally

Comment: It could have. I've seen recently some questions about problems connecting to localhost, but then why do you have SSL enabled on localhost? Those questions were not answered, AFAIK.

Comment: The server is running locally on a virtual machine that just mirrors off a master server when getting initially set up. Unfortunately I'm not too knowledgeable about the server set up as an intern for a company. I just don't understand why phantomjs would connect to the application but not casper. So something interesting, when I shut down the application while casper is trying to connect, casper would connect and I'm also able to capture a screenshot of the page before it's actually shut down.

Comment: Also maybe this is relevant: if I turn on onResourceError while connecting using phantomjs, I get these warning messages: Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL about:blank from frame with URL file://phantom.js. Domains, protocols and ports must match.

I read about instances where the above message is related to issues in casperjs but I haven't found a similar error situation.

Comment: These error messages usually appear when you're exiting and PhantomJS 1.9.8 (only) isn't done with something. It basically appears every time for CasperJS+PhantomJS 1.9.8

Comment: Okay well for now I've figured out how to access the server without SSL and that seems to work fine.